# Is it possible to buy UK train tickets for whole week?

Tags: uk, trains, tickets, trainline

I am going to get train every day from Gatwick Airport station to Horsham as well as return ways during the week. I found a mobile application — trainline — but there is only one ticket available to be bought. Is there something like a whole-week-train-ticket?

Comment: there are passes, but for UK residents they are very expensive. Are you visiting the UK?

Comment: Yes, I am visiting the UK, and I am Russian

Comment: Trainline is a third party app they add a small fee to the cost of a ticket when it's brought through them. National Rail Enquiries is the official site that does not add on such a fee.http://www.nationalrail.co.uk

Comment: All nationalrail.co.uk will do is forward to the actual train company, which is https://www.southernrailway.com/.

Comment: @MarkPerryman though you can actually buy the ticket from any train operator at the ticket price.  Some offer free postage (within the UK).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A [7-day standard class pass](http://www.brfares.com/#faredetail?orig=GTW&dest=HRH&rte=1000&tkt=7DS) between Gatwick Airport and Horsham costs £32.30, which is slightly cheaper than five day returns (£8.10 each, if you need to travel in the peaks).

This counts as a "season ticket" and is strictly personal, so it needs to be attached to a photocard for identification. If you don't have a photocard already, you may not be able to order the ticket online. Bring a passport photo to the staffed ticket counter when you buy the season ticket; a photocard should then be issued [free of charge](http://www.nationalrail.co.uk/times_fares/ticket_types/46571.aspx#photocard). Whether the time this will take you (and the cost of a photo) is worth the modest savings is for you to decide.

Comment: May student card of non-UK country give me a discount? Or my age - 24?

Comment: Where I can buy this ticket? In the link you sent price GBP48

Comment: @pure_true: You should be able to buy it at the ticket counter at Gatwick Airport station. I mistakenly linked to a first-class pass, fixed now.

Comment: If you have an international student identity card (which you should be able to get from your educational establishment) then they should give you any student discounts on that basis.

Comment: @DJClayworth: Do you know that there are any general student discounts available for these tickets? I can't find anything that looks like that.

Comment: @DJClayworth there are not any student discounts for season tickets.

Comment: @pure_true The closest thing to a discount is the [16-25 Railcard](https://www.16-25railcard.co.uk/).  It costs £30 and gives 1/3 of travel.  HOWEVER, it probably isn't valid on this journey until 9:30 and isn't worth it unless you are otherwise spending £90 on tickets anyway.

Answer (score 8):

> I am going to get train every day from Gatwick Airport station to Horsham as well as return ways during the week.

The first question is whether you need to travel during peak times or not. If you do (for example if you are commuting to a course that runs with a standard working day) then a 7 day season ticket is likely your cheapest option. If you can stick to off peak times then buying an individual ticket each day may be cheaper on some routes (turns out on this particular one the season ticket is marginally cheaper even if travelling off peak).

I'm not sure what the peak time rules for that particular journey are offhand. Note that the peak time rules can be different for "off peak day returns" and "off peak returns".

Advance tickets may be cheaper still but they tie you in to a particular train and are limited in number, probablly not worth it for a journey like this.

> May student card of non-UK country give me a discount? Or my age - 24?

There is the 16-25 railcard which is available to anyone in that age range. You should be able to buy it at any manned station with proof of age and a passport-style photo. Older full time students can also get it but the process for that is more awkward and likely to be impractical for someone studying outside the UK.

Unfortunately there are a number of caveats that mean it is unlikely to be of use to you.

1. Railcard discounts are not available on season tickets.
2. A £12 minimum fare applies for journeys starting between 4.30am-10am Monday to Friday excluding Advance Fares. This minimum fare does not apply on Public Holidays or throughout July and August.
3. The railcard itself costs £30. If you are only staying for a week and not making any long distance rail journeys it is unlikely to be cost-effective.

Comment: An off-peak day return is £6.90, so the 7-day season is still marginally cheaper than 5 of them.

Answer (score 2):

One option that will save you time but not money is to buy several (dated) tickets in one transaction.  When I've got to buy for odd days (e.g. it's not worth getting a season ticket just before Christmas) I often buy that day and the next.  I'm travelling at peak times; this may not be so easy if you're travelling off-peak.  It also requires a staffed ticket office rather than a machine.